# Hibernate envers single revision across multiple transaction

Tags: transactions, revision, hibernate-envers

I am using Spring v2.5.5/Hibernate v3.6.3 along with Hibernate Envers to audit the changes.

Currently a new revision is getting generated for each and every transaction.

But in my app, when I am doing very small unit of work too frequently, like 1 update per transaction, huge amount of audit records are getting generated.

Is it possible to Configure Envers for certain small unit of work to generate single revision for multiple transaction instead of 1 revision per transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Envers will generate a revision every time to save or update your entities. There isn't an easy way to override that. Envers is great because it super easy and quick to implement, but it can also generate a lot of audit records very quickly depending on the application. You might need to explore a custom auditing implementation using triggers or your own logging code if Envers is too noisy for your app.

Comment: This is the final solution which I could do. But need to know if it is possible via Envers itself.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not without overriding most of the core Envers functionality. It will be easier to write your own audit log, so you can customize what the unit of work is and what to log.