# Auditing in spring boot - How to custimise?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, audit-logging

I followed this document for implementing Auditing in spring boot.

(https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

Auditing is working fine but when the object is of type list means we are persisting as multiple entries in db.

I am passing this request object  for rest API :-

`

```
[
    {
        "name": "reddy"
    },
    {
        "name": "mani"
    }
]
```

`

for each object we are getting one audit log in db.

Is there any way to achieve as single entry in database?

Comment: multiple entries means multiple audit logs, that's normal behaviour.

Comment: is there any wait to overwrite normal behaviour?

Comment: as it's mentioned in this post, you can write your own audit log logic, not with envers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961831/2165146